# In clash of clans, I can't Change my Clan name?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am the leader of this clan and can't change the name? It's very strange because in the past I've always been able to change the name of a clan and all of a sudden the *clan name change* option goes away?

Comment: I'm sure clan names aren't changeable once they're created, as even name duplicates are allowed. (Like I've seen several clans take the same name, some with the same shield emblem, others different).

Comment: And could it be because your clan has members in it? (The change name functionality disappears after the first (well, second) person joins?)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the clan name, all the options are available to change are:

- Symbol,
- Description,
- Type (open, closed, invite only),
- Trophies (minimum required),
- War frequency and
- Clan location.